# Twisted mesh when parenting with automatic weights

Tags: mesh, rigging

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. Basically my mesh gets twisted when I parent to the bones with automatic weights.
I was trying to play around with the bone roll, but the best I could get was still not good. How should I set the bone roll to avoid twisting of the mesh? Here is a picture, maybe you will be able to tell me right away which bone properties should I be editing to fix it. 
I mean the left leg would be fine if not the twisted foot for some reason. The right side obviously has some problems with the upper leg part, but I just don`t know how to fix it without twisting the foot.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Okay so I kind of got it right by setting the bone roll. Still would be nice to know where did I make a mistake in the first place